# About deduction of sentence in Propositional calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I learnt that in propositional calculus, we could use modus ponens and axioms to derive a sentence. But, could we use proof by contradiction to derive a sentence? or it is an axiom. I am a bit confusing about the derivation of sentence here with the 'normal' Maths, in which I could use prove by contradiction, induction, exhaustion, and counter-example. Sorry, I don't know whether I express my question correctly, since I am still learning about basic mathematical logic. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, sir. So, in the 'normal Maths' what logical calculus system are we using. I am very confused...like when we talking about numbers and algebra.. thank you so much, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different versions of [Logical calculi (aka: Proof systems)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Other_logical_calculi).

In [Natural deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) we have rules only and there areb some rules that can be used in a proof by contradiction (see e.g. [Negation Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_introduction).

In so-called [Hilbert-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems#Implication_and_negation) proof systems we have some axioms and few rules of inference. Usually only [Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens).

In that case, proof by contradiction is an axiom, like e.g. the following:

> $(¬A→¬B) → ((¬A→B)→A)$,

or is derivable from axioms for conditional and negation.

---

Logical calculi are ways to formalize deductive inference.

There are many different approaches but all are aimed to formalize what is "commonly agreed" (since Aristotle and Euclid) as valid (i.e. truth preserving) deductive inference.

We can prove that different ways to formalize e.g. propositional logic are all equivalent in a rigorous mathematically defined way (see [Soundness and completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Soundness_and_completeness_of_the_rules)).

Thus, common mathematical practice does not need to be always formalized: the relevant fact is that we know how to reproduce with formal logic all known deductive inferences.

---

Having said that, you must be aware that propositional calculus is based on a very very simplified language, with which we can only express a limited amount of valid arguments.

In order to manage "real" mathematical reasoning we need [Predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).